# Running C++ program in android device

Tags: android, c++, linux, shell

I am writing a C++ code to execute 'top' command in android device. This is the code I use.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
     char buffer[1024];
     string result;
     system("top -n 1 |  head -n 4 | tail -n 3");
     FILE *memcpu= popen("top -n 1 |  head -n 4 | tail -n 3","r");
        while (!feof(memcpu)) {
            if (fgets(buffer, 1024, memcpu) != NULL)
                result+=buffer;
        }
        cout<<"result you need\n"<<result;
}
```

I want to run this file in adb device. Hence I build the program using command

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static -march=armv7-a name.cpp -o test
```

When I run the program, the string *result* is empty.

I tested the program by including `system("top -n 1");` line in the program. But I am not getting any output from adb shell (empty string).

I build the same program using g++ and run in linux pc. And at that time I am getting the correct output. What might be the reason that I am not getting desired output in adb shell from android device?

Comment: Are you running this `c++` code using `JNI` or any other way?

Comment: I am not using JNI. Basically I just build this program to device compatible executable file and put this executable to the system/bin folder using 'adb push' command. then I enter adb shell and execute the program from 'bin'.

Comment: Are all 3 programs (top, head and tail) available on your test device?

Comment: Yes, they are. I am able to execute these commands from shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build the program using command

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -static -march=armv7-a name.cpp -o test
```

a static binary is created. In order to link the libraries in android, the program must be built using android ndk build. And that solved the problem for me.